# Javascript/AngularJS Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

Im trying to create an app where there are multiple locations and you start to type in the name of a location and it narrows down the search. I am having trouble with this array. Here is my code:

```
var getSiteLoc = function($scope) {
var SiteLocs
$scope.SiteLocs = [{
  "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
  }
}, {
  "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
  }
}, {
  "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
  }
```

Now I would like to be able to look these up by name but cant seem to find out how. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you tried? You might look at this plunker for a starting point: http://plnkr.co/edit/XklvXtc1AZpndjLvXrh8?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/yodeg/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs |filter : search ">{{site.name}}</li>

    </ul>
```

js:

```
 $scope.SiteLocs = [
   {
  "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
  }

}
   , 
   {
  "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
  }
}
   , 
   {
  "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "visibility": "0",
  "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
  "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
  "Point": {
    "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
  }
   }];


});
```

Comment: How did you get this to work? It works in jsbin but not anywhere else. Also, there are more than 3 locations, there's a couple thousand, as i tried to add more in on jsbin it wouldnt work?  As you can tell im a novice to javascript/html so sorry if thats a dumb question.

Comment: I figured out how to add more locations so scratch that part.

Comment: in repeater you've got 'filter : search' which means your array will be filtered by 'search' and 'search' is bind to input. That how it works

Comment: So can we mark it as resolved ?

Comment: You're welcome, appreciate if you can mark question as solved. :)

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-mark-a-question-on-so-as-resolved

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work out for you.

```
$scope.SiteLocs = [{
    "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
    "visibility": "0",
    "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
        "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0"
    }
},
{
    "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
    "visibility": "0",
    "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
        "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0"
    }
},
{
    "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
    "visibility": "0",
    "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
    "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
    "Point": {
        "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0"
    }
}];

var getSiteLoc = function(needle)
{
    var hits = [], i = 0, loc;
    needle = needle.toLowerCase();
    //needle is the search string
    for(i; i < $scope.SiteLocs.length; ++i)
    {
        loc = $scope.SiteLocs[i];
        if(loc.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1)
            hits.push(loc);
    }

    return hits;
}
```

You're basically looping through all locations and checking if the needle is somewhere in the name.

Edit: Yes, I would also use the inbuilt filter utilities that AngularJS provides and other answers is pointing out.
You can read more about that on this page. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter expression with an ng-repeat directive

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.name">

<div ng-repeat="location in SiteLocs | filter:search">
   stuff goes here
</div>
```

[Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)